# Detect bubbles in PS plastic using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing

I have a PS/Polystyrene(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polystyrene) plastic with color.PS is transparent material after processing.Some time while processing bubbles are made.
I want to detect this bubbles using OpenCV.What can I do?What are the step for detect that bubbles?

This is a bubble that I want to detect.
http://goo.gl/frnD8Y

Comment: Due to the high contrast of the bubble edges, simple binarization and blob detection should do. You may also try to binarize after Sobel, this should make threshold setting more stable.

Comment: `I have a PS/Polystyrene plastic with color` can you define what are is the possible color range ? is it going to be purple every time ?

Comment: @Anmol_uppal,This image shows all possible colors...http://goo.gl/PSCJYw

Comment: @Yves Daoust..Is your simple binarization means convert image to black and white?

Comment: Yes, that's it. If you know where the plastic is, computing the average intensity is a good starting point to get a threshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to detect your bubles is to use the fact that they have a high surface curvature. High curvagure means it is going to reflect a light sorce placed almost at any orientation while a rflection from a planar surface is visible only from a limited range of viewpoints. If you introduce a few lightsources your buble will brighten up significantly while the background will not. Then you can just threshold it.

Alternatively you may want to first find a band using color then within a band find a cluster of gradient using a sum in a moving window. To zero in on a buble you can fit an ellipse to its gradient using openCV fit Ellipse function.

Answer (score 0):

From the given image you can segment it using the following code. If there is a bubble the the edges will be dark. so you can segment that easily

```
import numpy as np 

import cv2

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

filteredContour = []

img = cv2.imread('buble.png')

grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

binaryImage = np.uint8((grayImage < 20) *1)

plt.imshow(binaryImage)
```

Another way to detect air bubble is provide light from the side and use camera from the top. then you can segment that easily.